# MVC 5 asp.net Не могу добавить контроллер

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

После того, как пытаюсь добавить контроллер ругается и выдаёт такое сообщение. Сборку проекта делал, приложение тоже собирал, но всё равно что-то не так. Проверял на готовом проекте, всё работало.[image: MVC 5 Controller Error]

Comment: Использую Visual Studio 2019 Community, на другой машине всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Это глючная 19-ая студия. В 17-ой всё нормально заработает. Я сам целый день убил на поиск решения, вместо того, чтоб продуктивно поработать. Именно из-за этой ошибки откатился обратно на 17-ую и понял почему серьёзные конторы на старых версиях работают.

Comment: Это я понял, сам так же поступил.